# xPages - Creating a custom event

Tags: events, xpages

I have some client sided code I'd like to put into some kind of subroutine that I can call from the onChange event of each field. Lets say it's a field that represents Hours, the onchange event multiplies it with the payrate and comes out with the line item pay total. There are 7 entries like this and each time I do the calculation, I'd like to recalculate the totals from each line to arrive at the master total.

I see the xPages events has a piece called Components (Receive) I placed my masters total code there but at execution time, it doesn't recognize the handler name. The code looks like this;

```
    <xp:platformEvent id="platformEvent1"  eventName="HoursUpdated">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onevent" submit="false">
            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[// Perform totals calculation
    // get the dojo currency code
    dojo.require("dojo.currency");
    p1 = XSP.getElementById("#{id:PayAmount1}").innerHTML;
    p2 = XSP.getElementById("#{id:PayAmount2}").innerHTML;
    p3 = XSP.getElementById("#{id:PayAmount3}").innerHTML;
    p4 = XSP.getElementById("#{id:PayAmount4}").innerHTML;
    p5 = XSP.getElementById("#{id:PayAmount5}").innerHTML;
    p6 = XSP.getElementById("#{id:PayAmount6}").innerHTML;
    p7 = XSP.getElementById("#{id:PayAmount7}").innerHTML;  
]]></xp:this.script>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:platformEvent>
```

I call it from the onchange event like this;

```
HoursUpdated.dispatchEvent();
```

I get an error at runtime that it can't see the HoursUpdate event. When I look at the code, its there but given a pretty crazy ID. I even try calling it by that ID and it fails.

I saw a line in the help;

```
 XSP.publishEvent(...)
```

I'm not sure where to place it. The help in this area isn't real good.

Comment: It looks like you get a handle to each element's innerHTML, but you don't do anything with it in the script. Am I correct in thinking it's an incomplete script?

Comment: Yes, its incomplete. I'll write the rest when I see that the elements are translated properly in the debugger. (I should have noted that, but it was late, it was Friday.....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're over-thinking the problem, but I may just be missing the point.

You could put a scriptblock on the XPage and call your function from it. Assuming that the XPages is bound to the NotesDocument doc:

```
<xp:scriptBlock id="myScrip">
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[var updateValues = function(){
var p1 = getComponent("#{id:PayAmount1}").getValue();
var p2 = getComponent("#{id:PayAmount2}").getValue();
var p3 = getComponent("#{id:PayAmount3}").getValue();
var p4 = getComponent("#{id:PayAmount4}").getValue();
var p5 = getComponent("#{id:PayAmount5}").getValue();
var p6 = getComponent("#{id:PayAmount6}").getValue();
var p7 = getComponent("#{id:PayAmount7}").getValue();
var pTotal = p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + p5 + p6 + p7;
doc.setValue("#{id:PayTotal}", pTotal);
}
</xp:scriptBlock>
```

Then, in each field's onchange event, just use updateValues(); as the script.

Alternatively, put the computation (whatever it is) into the field where you want the updated value to display and have NO CODE in each onchange event, but mark the onchange to do a partial refresh of the total field.

Comment: The code I supplied was incomplete as I wanted to see them translated properly before finishing it. Isn't getComponent a server-sided command? I'm trying to do this completely on the client side. The fields are bound so they'll update when I save the doc. I'd rather keep it that way and avoid any refresh as I've observed it looses next-field focus.

Comment: getComponent is a global function and gets a handle to the UI component. My understanding is that its purpose is for use on the client side. It returns an object of the javax.faces.component.UIComponent class

Comment: I've always had bad luck trying to use the getComponent function. In this case the debugger showed that it translated the fields OK, but it still came back with issues trying to get a handle on the field. Changed it back to XSP.getElementById and it works like a champ. Anyway, the <xp:scriptblock> was exactly what I was looking for. Many Thanks!